# Sql procedure to search

Tags: sql, t-sql, procedure

I have a stored procedure that will search the whole database. This is the procedure

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE spGetSearchResults
    @table varchar(50) = null,
    @case varchar(50) = null,
    @value varchar(100) = null
as

exec('Select * from ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @case + 'like ''%'+ @value +'%''')
```

But for some reason it gives me an error Incorrect syntax near '%(value text)%'

but if i do a normal select statement with the values hard coded then it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some white-space. Put a space before `like`...

```
exec('Select * from ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @case + ' like ''%'+ @value +'%''')
```

That said, this procedure raises a [sql injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) flag...

Comment: Yea, i thought of that before. But this isnt going public, it's a small project for school

Comment: @mario you reminded me of this: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: ahhaha @lcarus thats soo priceless :P It's not that i am not able to fix it, more like too lazy to make more procedures when this one will do it. Making databases isnt my thing

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem.  You need to add a space in front of your `like` clause.  This should do it for your `exec()` call:

```
exec('Select * from ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @case + ' like ''%'+ @value +'%''')
```

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1. It's a very bad practice to execute code like this. Your stored procedure is prone to SQL Injection attacks
2. Don't do `select * from ...` it's an antipattern. You should procure to list exactly the columns you need from the table. Several benefits: improves performance, improves readability, avoid unexpected bugs if someone adds/removes columns to a table and you are doing an `insert into table select * ...`

Your proc as it stands does not have any syntax errors itself but you are getting the syntax errors when you call it because you forgot a space after `@case` so it prints something like:

> Select * from text WHERE textlike '%text%'